# How to use levigo

Tags: go, leveldb

I want to use leveldb in go,and find the [levigo](http://gowalker.org/github.com/jmhodges/levigo) tool
I try to build with the follow command

> go get github.com/jmhodges/levigo

Then I got failed with error:

```
/home/fun/workspace/study/leveldb/test/libleveldb.a(env_posix.o): In function `leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::StartThreadWrapper(void*)':
env_posix.cc:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/home/fun/workspace/study/leveldb/test/libleveldb.a(env_posix.o): In function `leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::NewLogger(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::Logger**)':
env_posix.cc:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/home/fun/workspace/study/leveldb/test/libleveldb.a(env_posix.o): In function `leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::NewSequentialFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::SequentialFile**)':
env_posix.cc:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
env_posix.cc:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

then I try to run :

> CGO_CFLAGS="-I/path/to/leveldb/include" CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/leveldb/lib" go get github.com/jmhodges/levigo

it does not work and report almost the same error .
anybody know what happened and how to fix it?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my installation of levigo:

```
$ uname -a
Linux peter 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ go version
go version devel +037a28ab0725 Thu Aug 22 12:13:54 2013 +0900 linux/amd64
$ sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libleveldb-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ go get -v github.com/jmhodges/levigo
github.com/jmhodges/levigo (download)
github.com/jmhodges/levigo
$
```

What output do you get if you run these commands?

Comment: I try your commands step by step,and it failed on the last step,the errors it reported are the same as before

Comment: I tried again,and when I run the last command,it report the errors as following:                                               fun@fun:~$ go get -v  github.com/jmhodges/levigo
github.com/jmhodges/levigo
# github.com/jmhodges/levigo
1: error: 'leveldb_free' undeclared (first use in this function)
1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
1: error: 'leveldb_compact_range' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my installation and it worked successfully:

- install leveldb:

  > $ tar zxvf leveldb-1.12.0.tar.gz
  >
  > $ leveldb-1.12.0/
  >
  > $ make
  >
  > $ sudo cp -r include/leveldb /usr/include/
  >
  > $ sudo cp libleveldb.* /usr/lib/
- install levigo:

  > $ go get github.com/jmhodges/levigo